# Australian visa for 1 year

Tags: visas, australia, novice-travellers

I'm a little unsure about the Australian visa system. I've looked into which industries for the skills occupation list, but I'm unsure if that's relevant for 1 year or a full migration. I'm from the UK, looking to travel with my girlfriend there for 1 year, and work while I'm out there. My background is .NET development and my girlfriends is graphic design. We would be staying with my family initially. Any help is appreciated

Comment: And should review the [various Australian visa options](http://www.australia.gov.au/help-and-contact/faqs/visas-and-immigration) for that which matches your plans.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please refer to [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) regarding this site Q&A scheme.  As it stands your question isn't really a question and lack specificity for any site to be valid.